# cant access a created class inside of a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple board game engine for html5 javascript but I cant seem to access any classes inside functions or functions in other classes. I can only make a new class outside of all functions:

```html
<canvas id = "canvas" width = "640" height = "480" style = "border: 1px solid gray; width: 640px; height: 480px;" >
</canvas>

<script>
    
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    class Board {
        construtor(height, width, cellSize, spaceing) {
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
            this.cellSize = cellSize;
            this.spaceing = spaceing;
            this.board = new Array(width).fill(new Array(height).fill(new Cell("black",1)));
        }
        
        draw() {
            var x = 0;
            this.board.forEach(function (cell) {
                ctx.fillStyle = cell.color;w
                ctx.fillRect(
                    this.spaceing + (x * (this.cellsize + this.spaceing)),
                    this.spaceing,
                    this.cellSize,
                    this.cellSize,
                );
                x++;
            });
        }
    }
    
    
    

    class Cell {
        construtor(color, value) {
            var color = color;
            var value = value;
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    setup();

    function setup() {
        var board = new Board(3,3,10,1);
        board.draw();
    }
   
    
</script>
```

Please help! I would love to make progress.
the only workaround is to make all the variables at the start but that's really inefficient and was to many problems

Comment: You have `construtor` instead of `constructor` in both classes.

Comment: Keep your browser's developer console open to see errors reported. (Except I guess that might not report an error!)

Comment: "*I cant seem to access any classes inside functions or functions in other classes*" - what makes you think that? What does not work, what errors do you get?

Comment: @Pointy I'm not sure that this would have triggered an error.  A JS class doesn't require a constructor and misspelled functions wouldn't really trigger an error either.

Comment: @zero298 yes I just verified that! (Though there is a stray comma in a function call.)

Comment: Notice that you are creating only a single instance of your `Cell` and reference it from everywhere in your board array. What you actually want is `this.board = Array.from({lenght: width}, () => Array.from({length: height}, () => new Cell("black",1)));`

Comment: If fixing your spelling error *does* fix your issue, please close this question as it stems from a *"a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."*.

Comment: ok so I fixed the misspelling and making the array, but I get the same error in chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Board.draw (index.html:20)
    at setup (index.html:50)
    at index.html:46

Comment: I think this means that the board is still undefined

Comment: just used a for loop